# POST Data in URL when pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button below. When I press it, my form data is displaying in my URL like so:

`?name=&email=&phone=&message=`

I dont want that and im unsure of why its there considering there is no POST on my form and my button is using a jquery post method.

Heres the form and button in question:

```
               <form class="form">
                    <p type="Message"><input type="text" name="message"></p>
                    <button id="clickMe">Send Message</button>
                </form>
```

Heres the jquery on my button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
        var data = {};
        data.name="kevin";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is url option? And add `$('#clickMe').on('click', function(e) {` `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: and add a `type="button"` to your button to tell the browser that it's not a 'submit' button for your form (just to be sure together with the preventDefaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to prevent the form from submitting. You can add inside of your click handler ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)):

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

*Note the `e` inside `function(e)` so that you capture the event object.*

If you want to **POST** the form data add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` element ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_POST_method)):

```
<form action="http://foo.com" method="post">
```

But if your goal is *not* to post the form but only send an ajax request I don't think it matters what `method` attribute is set to.